# iOS - Lower volume before playing video

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Sometimes I want to play a video but I'm in a meeting or a place where I can't afford to wait for the video to start to then quickly press the volume buttons to make it softer.

Is there any way I can mute the audio for a video before playing it? It seems like a valid scenario.

Comment: have headset ready to plug them in :)

Comment: Is this the only way? It feels wrong not to let the user mute his phone unless it first starts loudly

Comment: what happened to your volume button  on the ipad?

Comment: Change the setting for the volume buttons to make them affect system sound, not ringtones. Settings app > Sounds > "Ringers and Alerts" section > turn off Change with Buttons. Or just use the Silence button on the side of the device.

Answer (score 4):

You can lower volume without playing the video.

[image: ios control center]

from [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147102/how-can-i-lower-the-media-volume-on-my-iphone-when-no-media-are-playing):

> The control center works (swipe up from bottom of screen and slide volume slider as desired).
>
> In iOS 9 at least, you can also go Settings -> Sounds and under the Ringer and Alerts section, turn off "Change with Buttons", then use the volume buttons on the side of the phone to adjust the media volume. You can leave this option off to always have media volume control with the hardware buttons if you are OK with the ringer volume being just off or on at a preset level using the silent toggle switch on the side of the phone.

Answer (score -1):

While there should be a better way to choose which volume to use, and changing the settings option of Change with Buttons to Off, there is a much easier way to control the volume of the media you’re watching instead of paying attention in meetings at work. 
Simply put (I assume you need it simple since you obviously have a low attention span), turn your privacy on. On the iPhone, it’s the little switch over the volume buttons on top left side of phone. 
Then, you can open your dancing piglets video, set the volume while it’s playing, then turn your privacy off again. 
There.  Have a good meeting. Hope they don’t ask you any questions that aren’t about princess penelope and the piglets of penzance.